# Visibility:collapse is rendered as visibility:hidden

Tags: css

> **Collapse**
>
> Only for `table` elements. `collapse` removes a row or column, but it does not affect the `table` layout. The space taken up by the row or column will be available for other content.
>   If collapse is used on other elements, it renders as `hidden`.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp

However, the element is still taking up space like `visibility: hidden`. I've tested on Safari and Chrome. Anyone have a solution where the `table` layout is maintained but the space is removed?

Comment: What element? I don't see any code.

Comment: the link to http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp clearly specifies that if you want to creat invisible elemets that do not take place, you should use display instead of visibility.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: The issue with using display: none is that it affects the table layout. I want to maintain the table layout and hide the element.

Comment: If you remove a row or column you will have to re-layout the table. With `collapse` you do not have that issue. Are you sure you want that?

Comment: @Dipaks, `display: none` takes an element out of the flow.  `visibility: hidden` does not.

Comment: @Dipaks That is, `display:none` takes up no space, while `visibility:hidden` still takes up space but is invisible.

Comment: @Matt that's right, I do not to re-lay out the table.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42252682/3597276

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It won't work as intended on all browsers, only Firefox and IE (I can't confirm IE right now). The [MDN docs on `visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/visibility) say:

> The support for `visibility:collapse` is missing or partially incorrect in some modern browsers. In many cases it may not be correctly treated like `visibility:hidden` on elements other than table rows and columns.

You can test it with this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/meT7k/. In Chrome, the first row is rendered as `visibility: hidden`. In Firefox, `collapse` is applied correctly.

In Chrome, you get the desired results when applying `display: none` to the row instead. However, that will probably force a re-layout of the whole table (e.g., column widths may change after the `display` property is changed).

Comment: bfavaretto, seems like visibility:collapse isn't incorporated into browser support for webkit browsers.

Comment: Looks like that's it. FF supports it, and according to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531180(v=vs.85).aspx), ie8+ supports it too.

Comment: It is a little late but you can get it to work in Chrome [this way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807564/hiding-a-tr-while-still-involving-it-in-width-calculations/25807729#25807729)

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the contents in a `<span></span>` and set the display to none.

Comment: `display: none` takes an element out of the flow.  `visibility: hidden` does not.

Comment: display:none forces a re-lay out of the table.

Comment: Just to clarify, my suggestion was to wrap the cell contents in a span, which should not affect the table.

Comment: how do you undo the display: none? is it gone forever?

Comment: To wrap a cell in a span would be invalid html.